# Using Sharepoint web-services with Coldfusion

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, coldfusion

I'm running CF8 and trying to use the web-services of Sharepoint WSS 3.0. I have not been able to authenticate due to the use of NTLM of the Sharepoint side.

I read that if you save the WSDL on the CF server you can work around the authentication while still generating a stub, but I have been unsuccessful with that as well.

Does any one have an example or advice on how to get Coldfusion to use Sharepoint's web-services? Even an easy function like GetListCollection() would help.

Answer (score 1):

Not the greatest answer but ColdFusion 9 has built-in capabilities to talk to SharePoint. ColdFusion 9 handles your issue out of the box.

Comment: While Coldfusion 9 looks great, we are not quite ready to upgrade all of our servers quite yet ($). Also, ideally I'd like to have a solution running before CF9 comes out of Beta.